# Re-ordering div using CSS

Tags: css

I would like to re-order some div using only CSS if possible. 
Here is the HTML sample I want to re-order:

```
<div class="block1">
  Block1
</div>
<div class="block2">
    <div class="subblock1">S-Block1</div>
    <div class="subblock2">S-Block2</div>
    <div class="subblock3">S-Block3</div>
</div>
```

And this is the graphical result I want:

```
S-Block1
S-Block2
Block1
S-Block3
```

I already tried playing with `display: flex;` and `order: X` but with no success. The main problem lays in the fact that I want to split the `block2` before and after the `block1`. The `flex` display only allow me to change order of block of the same "level".

I would really like to have a solution that doesn't not use JavaScript to re-write the DOM (by taking subblock3 and putting it elsewhere to please my CSS) if possible.

Comment: There is no CSS solution for this, not even flexbox.

Comment: Why do you need the 2 parent blocks?

Comment: You could fake it by adding space and manually positioning each block in the same media query where you were trying to change the order, but that's not going to produce dependable results. This would require JS to do right.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's my fear, but I wanted to try my last resort before throwing some more JS into my app.

Comment: @LGSon: HTML is provided by some external tool which injects the HTML into my page, I don't have hands on it unless I modify the lib.

Comment: Have any of these blocks by any chance a fixed height/width?

Comment: The sub blocks could but I'd prefer not, and the block1 contains a textarea, so expandable etc…

Comment: Ok, the good thing is, it is an easy and simple script which simply move the div in block 1 in between subblock 2 and 3 on load and will cause less to nothing on performance ... and if loaded using AJAX maybe even less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears **this is not possible** and *javascript is not an option* for my problem.

Here is the sample code I used (jQuery needed).

```
$(".subblock2").prependTo(".form-wrapper");
$(".subblock1").prependTo(".form-wrapper");
```